# Microsoft Dynamics Business Central Integration

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-business-central

I there a way to create sales cycles and cycle stages using Microsoft Dynamics Business Central API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the documentation for `v1.0` and `beta` version and currently there is no way to create sales cycles and cycle stages.

Comment: I appreciate your response, we already give up Microsoft dynamics business central integration